# MySQL: LIKE Query Help?

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my table called `student_id`, and I am storing the student IDs associated with a particular record in that column, delimited with a `|` character. Here are a couple sample entries of the data in that column:

```
 243|244|245 
 245|1013|289|1012
 549|1097|1098|245|1099
```

I need to write a SQL query that will return records that have a `student_id` of `245. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store multiple values in the `student_id` field, as having exactly one value for each row and column intersection is a requirement of [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). This is a Good Thing for many reasons, but an obvious one is that it resolves having to deal with cases like having a `student_id` of "`1245`".

Instead, it would be much better to have a separate table for storing the student IDs associated with the records in this table. For example (you'd want to add proper constraints to this table definition as well),

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_student_id (
   mytable_id INTEGER,
   student_id INTEGER
);
```

And then you could query using a join:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable JOIN mytable_student_id 
   ON (mytable.id=mytable_student_id.mytable_id) WHERE mytable_student_id.student_id = 245
```

Note that since you didn't post any schema details regarding your original table other than that it contains a `student_id` field, I'm calling it `mytable` for the purpose of this example (and assuming it has a primary key field called `id` -- having a primary key is another requirement of 1NF).

Comment: I think that should be `WHERE mytable_student_id.student_id = 245`

Answer (score 0):

@Donut is totally right about First Normal Form: if you have a one-to-many relation you should use a separate table, other solutions lead to ad-hoccery and unmaintainable code.

But if you're faced with data that are in fact stored like that, one common way of doing it is this:

`WHERE CONCAT('|',student_id,'|') LIKE '%|245|%'`

Answer (score 0):

Again, I agree with Donut, but this is the proper query to use if you can't do anything about the data for now.

```
WHERE student_id like '%|245|%' or student_id like '%|245' or student_id like '245|%'
```

This takes care of 245 being at the start, middle or end of the string.  But if you aren't stuck with this design, please, please do what Donut recommends.